# jquery Populating HTML select with options and setting a default results in default showing blank

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using this jquery code below to put a list of countries into a select option and set the user's country as the default.

If I console log, the code shows I am recognising the user country correctly and in my project it has a blank where "United Kingdom" should be and that option is selected, it is just blank.

Why is this and what I should try doing differently?

````
  const sortedData = result.data.sort();
  for (var i = 0; i < sortedData.length; i++) {
    if (sortedData[i] === userCountry) {
      $("#country-selector").append(
        $("<option selected>", {
          value: sortedData[i],
          text: sortedData[i],
        })
      );
    } else {
      $("#country-selector").append(
        $("<option>", {
          value: sortedData[i],
          text: sortedData[i],
        })
      );
    }
  }
};```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing the `selected` attribute in the element HTML code to parse, appears to interfere with the setting of the attributes passed via parameters. Set the `selected` via the parameters as well instead, as `true` or `false`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < sortedData.length; i++) {
  $("#country-selector").append(
    $("<option>", {
      value: sortedData[i],
      text: sortedData[i],
      selected: sortedData[i] === userCountry // value of that comparison expression
                                              // will be either true or false
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: Amazing and a much cleaner code with out the if statement. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There's no overload to mix passing in an HTML snippet *and* apply additional attributes to that snippet.

Pick one or the other

- an HTML string (with attributes in the string)
  or
- an element name with attributes as the second parameter

---

According to [jquery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) you can create DOM nodes using two methods (using `$(..)` at least):

> `jQuery(html [,ownerDocument])`
> **html**
> A string of HTML to create on the fly

> `jQuery(html, attributes)`
> **html**
> A string defining a single, standalone, HTML element (e.g. `<div/>` or `<div></div>`).
> **attributes**
> An object of attributes, events and methods to call on the newly-created element

When you use `$("<option selected>", attrs)` the first argument is not a *"single, standalone element"* so jquery uses the first overload, passing your attributes as "ownerDocument" (which then gets ignored as it's the wrong type).

Comment: Took me a while to understand what you meant but totally see it now. Thank you for taking time to explain!